# Cannot detect backspace in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I'm developing a "Singlish" typing part for my website(a unicode converter). I found a complete code example from the internet. It has two text boxes.like this,

```html
<textarea  onkeyup="startText();" onclick="startText();" style="font-size: 12pt;
width: 600px;" name="box1" rows="7" ></textarea>


<input type="reset" value="Reset" style="position: relative; left: 500px; width: 100px;" />
<br />

<span class="TableText">Unicode (යුනිකෝඩ්)</span><br />

<textarea onkeyup="startText();" onselect="startText();" onclick="startText();" style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Potha, Malithi Web , Arial Unicode MS;
width: 600px;" name="box2" rows="7"></textarea>


<input onclick="copyit('txtBox.box2')" type="button" value="Copy" style="position: relative;
left: 500px; width: 100px;" />
```

when user tying in the first text box, second text box shows converted Sinhala character, but i need only one second text box and convert unicode when user typing. so i removed first text box and used this code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
<title>Real Time Unicode Converter</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: Potha;
src: url(POTHA0.eot);
}
.english{
color: purple;
}
.sinhala{
font-family: Iskoola Pota;
color: navy;
}
.title{
font-familiy:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:navy;
}
.title2{
font-familiy:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
}
.link{
font-weight: bold;
color: green;
border-width: 1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color: green;
cursor:hand;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
var text = "";
var nVowels;
    var charStr = "";
var consonants= new Array()
var consonantsUni= new Array()
var vowels= new Array()
var vowelsUni= new Array()
var vowelModifiersUni= new Array()
var specialConsonants= new Array()
var specialConsonantsUni= new Array()
var specialCharUni= new Array()
var specialChar= new Array()


vowelsUni[0]='ඌ'; vowels[0]='oo'; vowelModifiersUni[0]='ූ';
vowelsUni[1]='ඕ'; vowels[1]='o\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[1]='ෝ';
vowelsUni[2]='ඕ'; vowels[2]='oe'; vowelModifiersUni[2]='ෝ';
vowelsUni[3]='ආ'; vowels[3]='aa'; vowelModifiersUni[3]='ා';
vowelsUni[4]='ආ'; vowels[4]='a\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[4]='ා';
vowelsUni[5]='ඈ'; vowels[5]='Aa'; vowelModifiersUni[5]='ෑ';
vowelsUni[6]='ඈ'; vowels[6]='A\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[6]='ෑ';
vowelsUni[7]='ඈ'; vowels[7]='ae'; vowelModifiersUni[7]='ෑ';
vowelsUni[8]='ඊ'; vowels[8]='ii'; vowelModifiersUni[8]='ී';
vowelsUni[9]='ඊ'; vowels[9]='i\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[9]='ී';
vowelsUni[10]='ඊ'; vowels[10]='ie'; vowelModifiersUni[10]='ී';
vowelsUni[11]='ඊ'; vowels[11]='ee'; vowelModifiersUni[11]='ී';
vowelsUni[12]='ඒ'; vowels[12]='ea'; vowelModifiersUni[12]='ේ';
vowelsUni[13]='ඒ'; vowels[13]='e\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[13]='ේ';
vowelsUni[14]='ඒ'; vowels[14]='ei'; vowelModifiersUni[14]='ේ';
vowelsUni[15]='ඌ'; vowels[15]='uu'; vowelModifiersUni[15]='ූ';
vowelsUni[16]='ඌ'; vowels[16]='u\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[16]='ූ';
vowelsUni[17]='ඖ'; vowels[17]='au'; vowelModifiersUni[17]='ෞ';
vowelsUni[18]='ඇ'; vowels[18]='/\a'; vowelModifiersUni[18]='ැ';
vowelsUni[19]='අ'; vowels[19]='a'; vowelModifiersUni[19]='';
vowelsUni[20]='ඇ'; vowels[20]='A'; vowelModifiersUni[20]='ැ';
vowelsUni[21]='ඉ'; vowels[21]='i'; vowelModifiersUni[21]='ි';
vowelsUni[22]='එ'; vowels[22]='e'; vowelModifiersUni[22]='ෙ';
vowelsUni[23]='උ'; vowels[23]='u'; vowelModifiersUni[23]='ු';
vowelsUni[24]='ඔ'; vowels[24]='o'; vowelModifiersUni[24]='ො';
vowelsUni[25]='ඓ'; vowels[25]='I'; vowelModifiersUni[25]='ෛ';
nVowels=26;

specialConsonantsUni[0]='ං'; specialConsonants[0]=/\\n/g;
specialConsonantsUni[1]='ඃ'; specialConsonants[1]=/\\h/g;
specialConsonantsUni[2]='ඞ'; specialConsonants[2]=/\\N/g;
specialConsonantsUni[3]='ඍ'; specialConsonants[3]=/\\R/g;
//special characher Repaya
specialConsonantsUni[4]='ර්'+'\u200D'; specialConsonants[4]=/R/g;
specialConsonantsUni[5]='ර්'+'\u200D'; specialConsonants[5]=/\\r/g;
consonantsUni[0]='ඬ'; consonants[0]='nnd';
consonantsUni[1]='ඳ'; consonants[1]='nndh';
consonantsUni[2]='ඟ'; consonants[2]='nng';
consonantsUni[3]='ථ'; consonants[3]='Th';
consonantsUni[4]='ධ'; consonants[4]='Dh';
consonantsUni[5]='ඝ'; consonants[5]='gh';
consonantsUni[6]='ඡ'; consonants[6]='Ch';
consonantsUni[7]='ඵ'; consonants[7]='ph';
consonantsUni[8]='භ'; consonants[8]='bh';
consonantsUni[9]='ශ'; consonants[9]='sh';
consonantsUni[10]='ෂ'; consonants[10]='Sh';
consonantsUni[11]='ඥ'; consonants[11]='GN';
consonantsUni[12]='ඤ'; consonants[12]='KN';
consonantsUni[13]='ළු'; consonants[13]='Lu';
consonantsUni[14]='ද'; consonants[14]='dh';
consonantsUni[15]='ච'; consonants[15]='ch';
consonantsUni[16]='ඛ'; consonants[16]='kh';
consonantsUni[17]='ත'; consonants[17]='th';
consonantsUni[18]='ට'; consonants[18]='t';
consonantsUni[19]='ක'; consonants[19]='k';
consonantsUni[20]='ඩ'; consonants[20]='d';
consonantsUni[21]='න'; consonants[21]='n';
consonantsUni[22]='ප'; consonants[22]='p';
consonantsUni[23]='බ'; consonants[23]='b';
consonantsUni[24]='ම'; consonants[24]='m';
consonantsUni[25]='‍ය'; consonants[25]='\\u005C' + 'y';
consonantsUni[26]='‍ය'; consonants[26]='Y';
consonantsUni[27]='ය'; consonants[27]='y';
consonantsUni[28]='ජ'; consonants[28]='j';
consonantsUni[29]='ල'; consonants[29]='l';
consonantsUni[30]='ව'; consonants[30]='v';
consonantsUni[31]='ව'; consonants[31]='w';
consonantsUni[32]='ස'; consonants[32]='s';
consonantsUni[33]='හ'; consonants[33]='h';
consonantsUni[34]='ණ'; consonants[34]='N';
consonantsUni[35]='ළ'; consonants[35]='L';
consonantsUni[36]='ඛ'; consonants[36]='K';
consonantsUni[37]='ඝ'; consonants[37]='G';
consonantsUni[38]='ඨ'; consonants[38]='T';
consonantsUni[39]='ඪ'; consonants[39]='D';
consonantsUni[40]='ඵ'; consonants[40]='P';
consonantsUni[41]='ඹ'; consonants[41]='B';
consonantsUni[42]='ෆ'; consonants[42]='f';
consonantsUni[43]='ඣ'; consonants[43]='q';
consonantsUni[44]='ග'; consonants[44]='g';
//last because we need to ommit this in dealing with Rakaransha
consonantsUni[45]='ර'; consonants[45]='r';

specialCharUni[0]='ෲ'; specialChar[0]='ruu';
specialCharUni[1]='ෘ'; specialChar[1]='ru';
//specialCharUni[2]='්‍ර'; specialChar[2]='ra';

function startText() {
var s,r,v;

    document.txtBox.box2.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
       if(charCode == 8){
           console.log("");
       }
    charStr = charStr + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    text = charStr;
};
    
// +++++++++ Unicode conversion part starts here  ++++++++++++++++++ 

//special consonents
for (var i=0; i<specialConsonants.length; i++){
text = text.replace(specialConsonants[i], specialConsonantsUni[i]);
}
//consonents + special Chars
for (var i=0; i<specialCharUni.length; i++){
for (var j=0;j<consonants.length;j++){
s = consonants[j] + specialChar[i];
v = consonantsUni[j] + specialCharUni[i];
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
}
//consonants + Rakaransha + vowel modifiers
for (var j=0;j<consonants.length;j++){
for (var i=0;i<vowels.length;i++){
s = consonants[j] + "r" + vowels[i];
v = consonantsUni[j] + "්‍ර" + vowelModifiersUni[i];
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
s = consonants[j] + "r";
v = consonantsUni[j] + "්‍ර";
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
//consonents + vowel modifiers
for (var i=0;i<consonants.length;i++){
for (var j=0;j<nVowels;j++){
s = consonants[i]+vowels[j];
v = consonantsUni[i] + vowelModifiersUni[j];
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
}

//consonents + HAL
for (var i=0; i<consonants.length; i++){
r = new RegExp(consonants[i], "g");
text = text.replace(r, consonantsUni[i]+"්");
}
//vowels
for (var i=0; i<vowels.length; i++){
r = new RegExp(vowels[i], "g");
text = text.replace(r, vowelsUni[i]);
}

document.txtBox.box2.value=text;
    
}


// End -->

</script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<table width="600px">
<tr>
<td>
<form name="txtBox" id="txtBox">
<span class="TableText">Unicode (යුනිකෝඩ්)</span><br />

<textarea onkeyup="startText();" onselect="startText();" onclick="startText();" style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Potha, Malithi Web , Arial Unicode MS;
width: 600px;" name="box2" rows="7"></textarea>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but i have two problems,

1. I cannot delete character by pressing  backspace. It removes character and shows again the same character.
2. There is a delay between typing and converting. When i typed a letter it not converting unicode quicly. It also shows the english letter and then converts to the sinhala character.How to remove this delay?

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: change `onkeypress` to `oninput`

Comment: Regardless of where the insertion point is placed, new characters are inserted at the end. The language attribute for script elements is removed, type is unnecessary. HTML comment delimiters are ancient voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of

```
charStr = charStr + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
text = charStr;
```

1. Assume before pressing backspace, your "text" = "aabbcc"
2. When backspace pressed, it firstly remove the last character of your text area by browser (from keydown event which is fired before keypress event)
3. At this time, your "text" is : "aabbcc\8" but your textArea show: "aabbc"
4. When your keypress done, the keyStart() continue its flow, and it go to the statement

   document.txtBox.box2.value = text;

which will set the value of your text area into "aabbcc\8" (you cant see \8 character because it is invisible)

5. To make it work with backspace character, change your keypress event like bellow:

   ```
    document.txtBox.box2.onkeypress = function(evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
      if (charCode == 8) {
         charStr = document.txtBox.value;
      } else {
         charStr = charStr + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
     }
    text = charStr;
    };
   ```

Comment: I tried that,Not working,still same problem.sorry pal

Comment: What is the remain problem?

Comment: Unicode conversion part is not working. Only shows English characters

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this:

> I cannot delete character by pressing backspace. It removes character
>   and shows again the same character.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
<title>Real Time Unicode Converter</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: Potha;
src: url(POTHA0.eot);
}
.english{
color: purple;
}
.sinhala{
font-family: Iskoola Pota;
color: navy;
}
.title{
font-familiy:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:navy;
}
.title2{
font-familiy:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
}
.link{
font-weight: bold;
color: green;
border-width: 1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color: green;
cursor:hand;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
var text = "";
var nVowels;
    var charStr = "";
var consonants= new Array()
var consonantsUni= new Array()
var vowels= new Array()
var vowelsUni= new Array()
var vowelModifiersUni= new Array()
var specialConsonants= new Array()
var specialConsonantsUni= new Array()
var specialCharUni= new Array()
var specialChar= new Array()


vowelsUni[0]='ඌ'; vowels[0]='oo'; vowelModifiersUni[0]='ූ';
vowelsUni[1]='ඕ'; vowels[1]='o\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[1]='ෝ';
vowelsUni[2]='ඕ'; vowels[2]='oe'; vowelModifiersUni[2]='ෝ';
vowelsUni[3]='ආ'; vowels[3]='aa'; vowelModifiersUni[3]='ා';
vowelsUni[4]='ආ'; vowels[4]='a\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[4]='ා';
vowelsUni[5]='ඈ'; vowels[5]='Aa'; vowelModifiersUni[5]='ෑ';
vowelsUni[6]='ඈ'; vowels[6]='A\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[6]='ෑ';
vowelsUni[7]='ඈ'; vowels[7]='ae'; vowelModifiersUni[7]='ෑ';
vowelsUni[8]='ඊ'; vowels[8]='ii'; vowelModifiersUni[8]='ී';
vowelsUni[9]='ඊ'; vowels[9]='i\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[9]='ී';
vowelsUni[10]='ඊ'; vowels[10]='ie'; vowelModifiersUni[10]='ී';
vowelsUni[11]='ඊ'; vowels[11]='ee'; vowelModifiersUni[11]='ී';
vowelsUni[12]='ඒ'; vowels[12]='ea'; vowelModifiersUni[12]='ේ';
vowelsUni[13]='ඒ'; vowels[13]='e\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[13]='ේ';
vowelsUni[14]='ඒ'; vowels[14]='ei'; vowelModifiersUni[14]='ේ';
vowelsUni[15]='ඌ'; vowels[15]='uu'; vowelModifiersUni[15]='ූ';
vowelsUni[16]='ඌ'; vowels[16]='u\\)'; vowelModifiersUni[16]='ූ';
vowelsUni[17]='ඖ'; vowels[17]='au'; vowelModifiersUni[17]='ෞ';
vowelsUni[18]='ඇ'; vowels[18]='/\a'; vowelModifiersUni[18]='ැ';
vowelsUni[19]='අ'; vowels[19]='a'; vowelModifiersUni[19]='';
vowelsUni[20]='ඇ'; vowels[20]='A'; vowelModifiersUni[20]='ැ';
vowelsUni[21]='ඉ'; vowels[21]='i'; vowelModifiersUni[21]='ි';
vowelsUni[22]='එ'; vowels[22]='e'; vowelModifiersUni[22]='ෙ';
vowelsUni[23]='උ'; vowels[23]='u'; vowelModifiersUni[23]='ු';
vowelsUni[24]='ඔ'; vowels[24]='o'; vowelModifiersUni[24]='ො';
vowelsUni[25]='ඓ'; vowels[25]='I'; vowelModifiersUni[25]='ෛ';
nVowels=26;

specialConsonantsUni[0]='ං'; specialConsonants[0]=/\\n/g;
specialConsonantsUni[1]='ඃ'; specialConsonants[1]=/\\h/g;
specialConsonantsUni[2]='ඞ'; specialConsonants[2]=/\\N/g;
specialConsonantsUni[3]='ඍ'; specialConsonants[3]=/\\R/g;
//special characher Repaya
specialConsonantsUni[4]='ර්'+'\u200D'; specialConsonants[4]=/R/g;
specialConsonantsUni[5]='ර්'+'\u200D'; specialConsonants[5]=/\\r/g;
consonantsUni[0]='ඬ'; consonants[0]='nnd';
consonantsUni[1]='ඳ'; consonants[1]='nndh';
consonantsUni[2]='ඟ'; consonants[2]='nng';
consonantsUni[3]='ථ'; consonants[3]='Th';
consonantsUni[4]='ධ'; consonants[4]='Dh';
consonantsUni[5]='ඝ'; consonants[5]='gh';
consonantsUni[6]='ඡ'; consonants[6]='Ch';
consonantsUni[7]='ඵ'; consonants[7]='ph';
consonantsUni[8]='භ'; consonants[8]='bh';
consonantsUni[9]='ශ'; consonants[9]='sh';
consonantsUni[10]='ෂ'; consonants[10]='Sh';
consonantsUni[11]='ඥ'; consonants[11]='GN';
consonantsUni[12]='ඤ'; consonants[12]='KN';
consonantsUni[13]='ළු'; consonants[13]='Lu';
consonantsUni[14]='ද'; consonants[14]='dh';
consonantsUni[15]='ච'; consonants[15]='ch';
consonantsUni[16]='ඛ'; consonants[16]='kh';
consonantsUni[17]='ත'; consonants[17]='th';
consonantsUni[18]='ට'; consonants[18]='t';
consonantsUni[19]='ක'; consonants[19]='k';
consonantsUni[20]='ඩ'; consonants[20]='d';
consonantsUni[21]='න'; consonants[21]='n';
consonantsUni[22]='ප'; consonants[22]='p';
consonantsUni[23]='බ'; consonants[23]='b';
consonantsUni[24]='ම'; consonants[24]='m';
consonantsUni[25]='‍ය'; consonants[25]='\\u005C' + 'y';
consonantsUni[26]='‍ය'; consonants[26]='Y';
consonantsUni[27]='ය'; consonants[27]='y';
consonantsUni[28]='ජ'; consonants[28]='j';
consonantsUni[29]='ල'; consonants[29]='l';
consonantsUni[30]='ව'; consonants[30]='v';
consonantsUni[31]='ව'; consonants[31]='w';
consonantsUni[32]='ස'; consonants[32]='s';
consonantsUni[33]='හ'; consonants[33]='h';
consonantsUni[34]='ණ'; consonants[34]='N';
consonantsUni[35]='ළ'; consonants[35]='L';
consonantsUni[36]='ඛ'; consonants[36]='K';
consonantsUni[37]='ඝ'; consonants[37]='G';
consonantsUni[38]='ඨ'; consonants[38]='T';
consonantsUni[39]='ඪ'; consonants[39]='D';
consonantsUni[40]='ඵ'; consonants[40]='P';
consonantsUni[41]='ඹ'; consonants[41]='B';
consonantsUni[42]='ෆ'; consonants[42]='f';
consonantsUni[43]='ඣ'; consonants[43]='q';
consonantsUni[44]='ග'; consonants[44]='g';
//last because we need to ommit this in dealing with Rakaransha
consonantsUni[45]='ර'; consonants[45]='r';

specialCharUni[0]='ෲ'; specialChar[0]='ruu';
specialCharUni[1]='ෘ'; specialChar[1]='ru';
//specialCharUni[2]='්‍ර'; specialChar[2]='ra';

function startText() {
var s,r,v;

    document.txtBox.box2.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
       if(evt.keyCode == 8){
           charStr = charStr.substring(0, charStr.length - 1);
           text = charStr;
       }
       else{
           charStr = charStr + String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);
           text = charStr;
       }
    
};
    
//special consonents
for (var i=0; i<specialConsonants.length; i++){
text = text.replace(specialConsonants[i], specialConsonantsUni[i]);
}
//consonents + special Chars
for (var i=0; i<specialCharUni.length; i++){
for (var j=0;j<consonants.length;j++){
s = consonants[j] + specialChar[i];
v = consonantsUni[j] + specialCharUni[i];
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
}
//consonants + Rakaransha + vowel modifiers
for (var j=0;j<consonants.length;j++){
for (var i=0;i<vowels.length;i++){
s = consonants[j] + "r" + vowels[i];
v = consonantsUni[j] + "්‍ර" + vowelModifiersUni[i];
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
s = consonants[j] + "r";
v = consonantsUni[j] + "්‍ර";
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
//consonents + vowel modifiers
for (var i=0;i<consonants.length;i++){
for (var j=0;j<nVowels;j++){
s = consonants[i]+vowels[j];
v = consonantsUni[i] + vowelModifiersUni[j];
r = new RegExp(s, "g");
text = text.replace(r, v);
}
}

//consonents + HAL
for (var i=0; i<consonants.length; i++){
r = new RegExp(consonants[i], "g");
text = text.replace(r, consonantsUni[i]+"්");
}
//vowels
for (var i=0; i<vowels.length; i++){
r = new RegExp(vowels[i], "g");
text = text.replace(r, vowelsUni[i]);
}

document.txtBox.box2.value=text;
    
}

   // document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
   //   if(e.keyCode == 8 && e.code == 'Backspace'){
   //      document.txtBox.box2.value=text.substring(0,text.length -1);
   //   }
   // }, false);

// End -->

</script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<table width="600px">
<tr>
<td>
<form name="txtBox" id="txtBox">
<span class="TableText">Unicode (යුනිකෝඩ්)</span><br />

<textarea onkeyup="startText();" onselect="startText();" onclick="startText();" style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Potha, Malithi Web , Arial Unicode MS;
width: 600px;" name="box2" rows="7"></textarea>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried 'onkeydown' before. Nicely working backspace but unicode conversion is incorrect

Comment: It's in the above code. I added comment to the starting point

Comment: Can you explain how the unicode conversion works? The main issue in this question of deletion is addressed. Do you have any character that need be inserted at end of the input string which marks the end of the string?

Comment: Yes. There are 9 char arrays in the code. when user typing a character it check array that the character contains. Then it replace text box with the correct Sinhalese character . I know little bit confusing ,but i think you can understand